# apex:repeat works on one page, but not another similar page

Tags: force.com-sites, visualforce

To perform some testing, I cloned a page and started making adjustments to a new section.  Once I had this completed, I cut and pasted the block of code to the original page (the one that was clone from) receives an error -- Save error:Syntax error.  Found 'BloomMap'

Does anyone know why it would work on one visualforce page and not on another -- especially almost identical pages.

Here is the code

Page

```
 <p>
      <apex:repeat value="{!BloomMap}" var="mpmon">
       <h4>{!mpmon}</h4>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <apex:repeat value="{!BloomMap[mpmon]}" var="weeks">
              <td>{!weeks}</td>
           </apex:repeat>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </apex:repeat>
    </p>
```

Controller (I have some clean up left to do)

```
public Map<String, List<String>> getBloomMap ()
  {

    List<String> weeks = new List<String>();
    List<String> newweeks = new List<String>();

    Integer mon = 0;
    Integer monthday = 0;
    String strMon = '';
    String strWeek = '';

    mp_bloom.clear ();  //Empty List    
    flowerBloomedDates.clear ();  // Empty list 
    weeks.clear();
        newweeks.clear();

         gardenPlant = [Select pp.name, pp.Id from Garden_Plant__c pp where id = :System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('gpid')]; 

         for (Flowers_Bloomed_this_Week__c fb : [Select Bloom_Date__c, Plant_Name__c from Flowers_Bloomed_this_Week__c where Plant_Name__c = :gardenPlant.Id])
         {

            List<String> tmp = new List<String>();
            strMon='';
            strWeek='';
            mon = fb.Bloom_Date__c.month();
            if (mon == 1) strMon='January ';
            if (mon == 2) strMon='February ' ;
            if (mon == 3) strMon='March ';
            if (mon == 4) strMon='April ' ;
            if (mon == 5) strMon='May ' ;
            if (mon == 6) strMon='June ' ;
            if (mon == 7) strMon='July ';
            if (mon == 8) strMon='August ' ;
            if (mon == 9) strMon='September ' ;
            if (mon == 10) strMon='October ';
            if (mon == 11) strMon='November ' ;
            if (mon == 12) strMon='December ';
    /*      
            monthday = fb.Bloom_Date__c.day();
            if (monthday <= 7) strWeek = strMon + 'Week 1';
            if (monthday >7 && monthday <= 14) strWeek = strMon + 'Week 2';
            if (monthday >14 && monthday <= 21) strWeek = strMon + 'Week 3';
            if (monthday > 21) strWeek = strMon + 'Week 4';
      */
            strWeek = 'Week of ' + strMon + String.valueOf(fb.Bloom_Date__c.toStartOfWeek().day());     
      //    strWeek += fb.Bloom_Date__c.year();

            strMon += fb.Bloom_Date__c.year();

            if (mp_bloom.isEmpty() == true )
            {
                weeks.add( strWeek);
                flowerBloomedDates.add(strMon);
                mp_bloom.put(strMon, weeks);
            }

            else
            {
                if (mp_bloom.containsKey(strMon) == true)
                {

                    if (mp_bloom.get(strMon) == null)
                    {
                        weeks.add(strWeek);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        weeks = mp_bloom.get(strMon);
                        weeks.add(strWeek);

                    }
                    mp_bloom.put(strMon, weeks);

                }
                else
                {
                    tmp.add(strWeek);
                    flowerBloomedDates.add(strMon);
                    mp_bloom.put(strMon, tmp);
                }
            }


         } 
       return mp_bloom;
  }
```

Comment: Please post relevant controller code.

Comment: I use the same controller for both pages.  The error occurs on saving the page, not the controller.

Comment: The VF code you've posted works for me in a test environment, which probably means the problem is somewhere else. I suggest commenting out sections of your page until you are able to save it without errors, and inspect the section with the problem.

Comment: @Jeremy showing you the right path. Just try to find out which code is creating issue

Comment: I think you should replace this line: `<apex:repeat value="{!BloomMap[mpmon]}" var="weeks">` with this: `<apex:repeat value="{!mpmon}" var="weeks">`

Comment: The line '<apex:repeat value="{!BloomMap[mpmon]}" var="weeks">' is the issue.  What I want it to do is iterate through that list of the Map.  If I replace the line with the one suggested -- '<apex:repeat value="{!mpmon}" var="weeks">' then I receive back the map key, but not the map value.

Comment: @Jeremy -- I have done this.   This is actually why I started with a cloned page, and then copied the code over.  I have narrowed down the line that has the issue, but I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: So you have two pages, one works one doesn't. What are the API versions of the pages?

Comment: GREAT IDEA!!  That worked!!  THANK YOU very much.  I only have 6 more hours to wrap this up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 0):

Just to get this off the list of unanswered questions. Jeremy Nottingham had the right suggestion, apparently the two pages had different API versions and updating the version of the problematic page was the solution.